# Python - All pairwise combinations of two datasets efficiently

Tags: python, merge, dataset

I want to create a data set consisting of all pairwise combinations of two csv columns. I am using Stata but it only allows having 2,147,483,647 observations. I am not really knowledgeable about python. Could I do it with Python and preferably efficiently? I can make some loops but I guess it will take forever.

Here is an example: I have a.csv like this (as a column:):
1
2
3
and I have b.csv like this (as a column:)
a
b
c
I want this as the output:
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,a
2,b
2,c
...
a.csv and b.csv each has around 7 million records.
any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:  It would also be very useful if I can do a "within-group" pairwise. Imagine a.csv and b.csv both have another column, say gender. And I want to do all pairwise of males and all pairwise of females (of course it is much more complicated. the attribute data has more than a 100 categories).

Comment: Do you really want the output to have *all* possible pairs?  If each of the 7 million a rows appear 7 million times (one for each b row), your output will have 49 trillion rows.

Comment: I know it is strange. But I need to create a complete graph (social networks) out of 7 million nodes and then need to delete most of the records based on some criteria. It would also be very useful if I can do a "within-group" pairwise. Imagine a.csv and b.csv both have another column, say gender. And I want to do all pairwise of males and all pairwise of females (of course it is much more complicated. the attribute data has more than a 100 categories).

Comment: Use a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Python is good at these things.
If two csv file is very large and python provide with iteration for it.

```
for line1 in open('really_big_file.csv'):
    for line2 in open('really_big_file.csv'):
        combine(line1, line2)
```

Python will iter every line data and release it, it is auto.